# Extract character between the first two characters

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery:

```
ab_col_jfsfhfd_ggg_sdf
arfd_am_fdsf_fddg_fg
d_fdf_fdddg_ffddd_f
```

I would like to extract those characters that go right after the first _ character and followed by the second _ character. I want to get the following:

```
col
am
fdf
```

I used the following regular expression to extract the characters but it does not work as intended:

```
^.*\_(\D+)\_.*$
regexp_replace(id,'^.*\\_(\\D+)\\_.*$' , '\\1')
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `split()`:

```
(split(col, '_'))[safe_ordinal(2)]
```

`split()` turns the string column to an array of values, given a separator (here, we use `_`). Then we can just grab second array element.

Comment: I am getting this erro: Array index 2 is out of bounds (overflow)

Comment: @Alex: then it looks like some of your strings to not contain character `_`. You can use `safe_ordinal()` to avoid that error (and return `null` in such case).

Answer (score 2):

`split()` is a very simply way of solving this.  But regular expressions are also quite simple:

```
with t as (
      select 'ab_col_jfsfhfd_ggg_sdf' as id union all
      select 'arfd_am_fdsf_fddg_fg' union all
      select 'd_fdf_fdddg_ffddd_f'
     )
select id, regexp_extract(id, '[^_]+', 1, 2)
from t;
```

The logic for the pattern is:  "Look for any string of characters that is not an underscore.  Then take the second one in the string."

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_extract`:

```sql
regexp_extract(id,'^[^_]+_([^_]+)')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/xjyoBa/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^_]+                    any character except: '_' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```